# DD-WRT on Linksys WRT54Gv8 has no sshd or Rflow options

Tags: router, services, dd-wrt, sshd

I'm playing with open source firmware for the first time, and seem to have dd-wrt running successfully on a Linksys cascading off my main router (which for fear of bricking, I have not flashed yet). The dd-wrt router is set as the dmz host of the upstream router and has its own subnet.

However in the web administrator panel, under Services>Services, there are no options for Sshd or Rflow, despite numerous tutorials indicating there would be, and the help menu giving descriptions of them. There is a telnet option, and I was able to telnet in fine. Any idea why they are missing and how to play?

I used dd-wrt.v24_micro_generic.bin as directed by the download page for my router (linksys WRT54Gv8.0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SSH isn't included per [version page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#File_Versions). The router database confirms this only has 2MB & the [peacock thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=51486) advises that it can only do micro. It advises (& other links below) you have to compress CFS to move to another version:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=289931

http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G_v8.0_%26_v8.2

Comment: Unfortunately these links no longer work